# How do I create a Laravel Logger that logs to a specific Elasticsearch Index?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, laravel-6

I have a logstash logger in my `config/logging.php` file that connects to my logstash instance:

```
        'logstash' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via'    => LogstashLogger::class,
            'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST'),
            'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_PORT'),
        ],
```

Using L6, and a tutorial, I created this LogstashLogger:

```
<?php

namespace App\Logger;

use Monolog\Formatter\LogstashFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\SocketHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class LogstashLogger
{

    /**
     * @param array $config
     * @return LoggerInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config): LoggerInterface
    {
        $handler = new SocketHandler("udp://{$config['host']}:{$config['port']}");
        $handler->setFormatter(new LogstashFormatter(config('app.name')));

        return new Logger(config('app.env'), [$handler]);
    }

}
```

The app I am working on is namespaced by feature and the client would like feature specific logs in Elasticsearch where each feature feeds an index. The idea we have is to have custom loggers for each index. Something like this:

```
        'feature1' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via'    => LogstashLogger::class,
            'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST'),
            'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_PORT'),

            'index' => feature1-index
        ],
```

or even better like this:

```
        'feature1' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via'    => Feature1LogstashLogger::class,
            'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST'),
            'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_PORT'),
        ],
```

I just have no idea on what the contents of `Feature1LogstashLogger` will be. I've scoured the net and have come up empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

tldr; I ended up using Logstash Multiple Pipelines. Each pipeline specifies its own config file. In each config file I used a different port and a different default index. This allowed me to specify different loggers in Laravel

1. Identify `path.settings` folder location
2. Place a `pipelines.yml` file in that location with contents similar to this:

```
- pipeline.id: index-name-1
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/index-name-1.conf"

- pipeline.id: index-name-2
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/index-name-2.conf"
```

The full list of what can be entered into the pipelines.yml file is [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/config/pipelines.yml)

3. In each of the config files add a full configuration of a pipeline:

```
index-name-1.conf
====================

input {
    udp {
        port => 500X
        type => syslog
      }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    enable_metric => false
    add_field => { "appFeature" => "Feature1" }
    remove_field => ['@version', 'host']
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
        index => "index-name-1-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

The `500X` can be 5001, 5002, or any port that you or your sysadmin determine to be available and free. If you are using docker, make sure to add the ports you need your config or compose file/yml

4. Make new channels for each pipeline in Laravel:

```
config/logging.php
==================

'index-name-1-channel' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via'    => LogstashIndexName1Logger::class,
            'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST'),
            'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_INDX-NM-1_PORT'),
        ],
```

5. Make the Logger Classes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Logger;

use Monolog\Formatter\LogstashFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\SocketHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class LogstashIndexName1Logger
{

    /**
     * @param array $config
     * @return LoggerInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config): LoggerInterface
    {
        $handler = new SocketHandler("udp://{$config['host']}:{$config['port']}");
        $handler->setFormatter(new LogstashFormatter(config('app.name'), 'IndexName1'));

        return new Logger(config('app.env'), [$handler]);
    }

}
```

I can successfully log with the channel: 
`Log::channel('index-name-1-channel')->debug('What happened?!');`

And I can now write kibana queries that are local to a single feature using the fields (or even tags). If there any suggestions or tips you may know for a better implementation, feel free to comment